# Inheritance - derived classes required to instantiate the base class constructor

Tags: c#, .net, oop, asp.net-core

I have lack of understanding in this basic concept of OOP. Here is an example:

Say I have a base repository which is derived by 3 different classes. The base class requires the dbContext in the constructor , injected by dependency injection. Because of this the child classes have to pass the dbContext every time I instantiate them. The requirement is simple: The base class should instantiate the Context for the child classes. Is that possible? I do not want the child classes to worry about the context. I just want them to call it.

Here is my base class.

```
        public class CastingBaseRepository<TEntity> : ICastingBaseRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class, IEntity
    { 
        private readonly CastingContext _context;
        public CastingBaseRepository(CastingContext context) => _context = context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));

        // Context property
        public CastingContext Context => _context;
}
```

Heres how the child class would be:

```
         public class CommercialJobsRepository : CastingBaseRepository<Audition>, ICommercialJobsRepository
            { 
    /* I do not want to use base(context) here. I need a way for this class to just call Context property from the derived class.. Possible? */

                private CastingContext _context;
                public CommercialJobsRepository(CastingContext context) : base(context)
                {
                    _context = context;
                }

                public async Task<IList<OpenJobs>> GetOpenJobs()
                {
// test code
                    var tt = await _context.Audition.Take(10).ToListAsync();
                    return new List<OpenJobs>();
                }
            }
```

Here is my context class

```
    public partial class CastingContext : DbContext
{
     public virtual DbSet<Audition> Audition { get; set; }
    public CastingContext(DbContextOptions<CastingContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

And here is the startup.cs

```
  public class Startup
    {

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            // DB Context

            services.AddDbContextPool<CastingContext>(options => { options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging(); options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("dbCast")); });
           }
}
```

I am using strategy pattern to determine which child class would be accessed at runtime. That too needs to have CastingContext injected the constructor which is again ugly. The point is, there should be only one class exposing the context to all derived classes or perhaps through a static method. Can you please help me understand how to do it?

Here is my Strategy class:

```
  public class JobsStrategyContext
{
    private readonly CastingContext _context;

    private readonly Dictionary<eBreakdownTypes, IJobsRepository> Strategies =
        new Dictionary<eBreakdownTypes, IJobsRepository>();

    public JobsStrategyContext(CastingContext context)
    {
        _context = context;

        Strategies.Add(eBreakdownTypes.Ftv, new FtvJobsRepository(_context));
        Strategies.Add(eBreakdownTypes.Commercial, new CommercialJobsRepository(_context));
        Strategies.Add(eBreakdownTypes.Theatre, new TheatreJobsRepository(_context));
    }


    public async Task<IList<OpenJobs>> GetOpenJobsBySubType(eBreakdownTypes breakdownType)
    {
        return await Strategies[breakdownType].GetOpenJobs();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot both at the same time use dependency injection *and* hardcode the instantiation of your dependency in the base class. If you want to inject the dependency from an external consumer, it needs to pass through the derived constructor.

*At best*, you can pass a service locator which the base constructor then uses to fetch the dbcontext, but then you're still handling the service locator in the derived class. But [service locators are no longer considered good practice](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/) because they have notable drawbacks such as decreasing readability/usability and becoming a general nuisance to handle in sufficiently large codebases.
While it would technically achieve what you want to achieve, don't start using static service locators. The costs **far** outweigh the benefits.

However, the problem outset doesn't quite make sense to me. If you're using dependency injection, I would assume you're using some sort of automated injection where you don't have to manually instantiate all dependencies.
Yes, you still need to mention the dbcontext as a (derived and base) constructor parameter, but your derived classes don't need to handle it (other than passing it to the base constructor. The effort to do so is minimal and it allows for maximum freedom in terms of dependency injection.

This is how inheritance works by design.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Say I do not want to use dependency injection in the base class i.e. the base class would not have Castingcontext injected in the constructor. Instead, I want to expose a method or a property that would initiate this DbContext... That is possible right? 
But DbContext would need a Connection string, that has to come from appSettings and which would again need some dependency to be injected. Any solution?

Comment: @AthAn: Is it possible? Sure. Is it a good idea? No. Dependency injection exists for a reason, and circumventing it for what amounts to a minimal syntax change (not passing one parameter to a base constructor) is not worth the loss of your dependency injection.

Comment: I see... that makes sense. Thanks for your help

Comment: @AthAn: App settings tend to circumvent normal dependency injection as they are handled more akin to environment variables that are statically available. Many developers I know reject this and still prefer to inject an app settings DTO instead, but that is IMHO a question of style. There is nothing wrong with statically fetching an app setting **if** you don't need to swap between connectionstrings on the fly (EF and the likes even use a default app setting key name so you don't have to handle it unless you need direct control over the selection between multiple connection strings)

Comment: Oh one more thing, What about the service layer passing the context. I have been thinking that service should not be aware of Dbcontext. It should just call the repository and the repository should handle DbContext. In my case, Since I am calling JobsStrategyContext class from the service layer, I am forced to use Dbcontext in service constructor. what do you think?

Comment: @AthAn: With dependency injection, the top level consumer (e.g. your web service) _does_ decide which dependencies get used. However, it is acceptable to confine the DbContext to the DAL and not use it in the dependency graph, **but** I prefer to simple delegate some of the dependency registration from the web service to the DAL so it can register the DbContext without the web service needing to have a direct reference to the DbContext (because you don't want an EF project reference in your web service). This way, you can both use injection _and_ avoid an EF library reference in the service.

Comment: @Flater: technically, you have an EF reference either way. It doesn't matter if the app knows anything directly about EF: it references a class library that references EF. As such, you'll end up with EF DLLs in your build. The only way to truly abstract the EF dependency is to keep it completely segregated from the web app (a separate API project/microservice(s) for example).

Comment: Thanks. so you are saying that Service layer can have access to dbContext?  because technically it references repositories that reference EF... right ? 
Then at some point, isn't it ok to directly EF from service layer, why have the repositories then? just trying to understand here

Comment: @ChrisPratt: By that definition, you're throwing out the whole concept of layer separation since different layers all communicate with each other in some way post-compilation. You're arguing an English semantical point and are ignoring the technical nature of the discussion. I didn't say you should avoid having EF DLLs in your build, I said you need to avoid directly referencing EF in your web service project so that when you move away from e.g. EF only the DAL is affected and you don't need to change the rest of your codebase.

Comment: @Shezi No, I suggest _not_ giving the service layer direct access to the DbContext. Either don't inject it as a dependency, or have a DAL class perform the `services.AddScoped<MyDbContext>()` (or similar) logic, and have your web service call this class. That way, the web service does not directly interact with any EF types. This discussion is getting out of bounds and if you need more help on this topic, it should be posted as a different question.

Comment: "Why have the repositories, then?" Indeed. The repository pattern makes no sense with EF or any ORM for that matter. Each DbSet is a repository, so EF already implements the pattern. Your service layer would be your abstraction. The service layer should depend directly on your context, and the app on the service layer. EF itself is your DAL.

Comment: @Flater: I'm pointing out that you're not removing dependencies by burying them in layers. There's still value to layers of course, but you need to be aware that there is inevitable bleed over.

Comment: @ChrisPratt: You're countering a point I never made with information that is not relevant to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is a functional limitation of C# as a language. You don't *have* to provide the same constructor(s) in child classes as you have in the base class, but you *must* satisfy those constructors in the base class. For example:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public BaseClass(Dependency dep) {}
}

public class ChildClass
{
    public ChildClass(Dependency dep) : base(dep) {}
}
```

Or:

```
public class ChildClass
{
    public ChildClass() : base(new Dependency()) {}
}
```

In either case, you somehow, someway must provide the `Dependency` instance to the base class constructor, but you may opt to not actually construct the child class with that dependency, and instead, get it internally.

However, in practical terms with something like `DbContext` which relies itself on dependencies being injected, it's going to require carrying that dependency all the way through: your child class will need a constructor where it can be injected in order to then pass down into the base class constructor.

Comment: Chris, I really appreciate your answer. The problem in hand is that the service layer is calling JobsStrategyContext (which is supposed to be a static class, because I do not want to create a new instance each time the service method is called)
But when i change this JobsStrategyContext class to a static class, I lose the ability to use dependency injection all together and thus no repository is then able to pass the constructor.
Should I not make JobsStrategyContext a static class and keep it like this? What do you suggest?

Comment: That's because statics and DI are fundamentally incompatible. If you're going to use DI (and if you're using ASP.NET Core you *are* going to use DI), then you should forego statics. If you want a single instance, you can register the class in singleton scope, but you should be using an actual class instance, not a static.

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide the dependency through the child class because, When you are creating an instance of the child class, the base class is also getting constructed and hence the dependencies must be supplied.

Of course for the ease of coding and managing these dependencies,you can use Use the IoC containers like **Unity** to handle the automatic dependency injections (The Unity Application dependency injection container with support for constructor, property, and method call injection)